# Implementing Listener inside Singleton class

Tags: android

I am using Android ExoPlayer, i created a singleton class called **SongPlaybackManager.java** to handle all the playback things (play, pause, next, previous, shuffle, repeat, etc.)

```
public class SongPlaybackManager implements Player.EventListener {

    private static SongPlaybackManager manager;
    private final SimpleExoPlayer player;

    private SongPlaybackManager() {
            //init player also addListener
            ...
            player.addListener(this);
    }

    public static SongPlaybackManager getInstance() {
            if (manager == null) {
                    manager = new SongPlaybackManager();
            }

            return manager;
    }

    //EventListener callbacks overrides
}
```

But i wonder if i have to remove the listener or not to prevent the leaking memory. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the issue here?

Comment: It's not actually an issue, i want to implement the Listener inside the singleton class, but I worry if it causes memory leaking or not.

Comment: Did you test memory leakage in android monitor?

Comment: I have not tested it yet, it is just my idea before implementation.

Comment: Usually Android Studio will warn you about possible leakage due to static member usages. If you are using the latest version and nothing shows up, I think you can rest assured there's none.

Comment: Thank mates, i will try and let you know the result